# Postfix doesn't send mail, complaining about "Host or domain name not found"

Tags: debian, postfix

I followed [these instructions](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/8/6/postfix-using-telnet-to-test-postfix) in order to send mail and here's the Postfix log:

```
Sep 26 00:46:24 tshepang postfix/smtpd[5728]: 8EE2464931: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 26 00:47:44 tshepang postfix/cleanup[5810]: 8EE2464931: message-id=<20110925224624.8EE2464931@tshepang>
Sep 26 00:47:44 tshepang postfix/qmgr[5772]: 8EE2464931: from=<tshepang@gmail.com>, size=350, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 26 00:48:04 tshepang postfix/smtp[5859]: 8EE2464931: to=<tshepang.test@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=127, delays=107/0.01/20/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
Sep 26 00:48:39 tshepang postfix/smtpd[5728]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

Also, this may be relevant (from "**/etc/postfix/main.cf**"):

```
myhostname = tshepang
mydestination = tshepang, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

I am running this on Debian 6.

Comment: Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` for invalid/non-responding resolvers.  Try to do a `host gmail.com`; see if you get results.

Comment: `host gmail.com` gives `gmail.com has address 74.125.233.24` on the line, and then
`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached` on the second. But it's strange because I can ping it.

Comment: How about `host -t mx gmail.com` ? You're right, though, this is somewhat odd.

Comment: Another thought: can you add your /etc/resolv.conf to the question?

Comment: relayhost is empty? I found that you should comment it out if you do not have any relayhost. Apart from that you are getting no MX-record from DNS. Try what Shadur suggests...

Comment: @Nils "`relay=none`" -- postfix already recognizes there's no relay specified so it tries to send to the primary MX

Comment: ... and it seems there is no MX-record.

Comment: Yeah. Signs point to a dodgy `resolv.conf`, possibly due to `network-manager` or `resolvconf` not quite playing ball.

Comment: Boosting a couple questions mentioned in comments that might help figure out what's going on: - Can you add your `/etc/resolv.conf` to the question? The output you describe from `host gmail.com` is a bit suspicious and could indicate an issue with your nameserver. - What, if any, response do you get from the command `host -t mx gmail.com` ? - Have you successfully sent mail to other systems from this computer? - Does your ISP have some kind of explicit policy that requires you to use their server as mail relay? If they do, a firewall blocking MX lookup requests might explain the weird behavior

Comment: I agree with this. It looks more like a DNS issue than a problem with Postifx (especially because of the `no servers could be reached` error from `host`).

Answer (score 7):

I used to have the same problem:

```
root@medusa:~# postqueue -p
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
079AC700080B      357 Wed Apr  3 13:47:47  root@medusa.yyyy.cz
(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxxx.cz type=MX: Host not found, try again)
                                         hmls@xxxx.cz
```

..

```
root@medusa:~# host -t MX xxxx.cz
xxxx.cz mail is handled by 10 e2sgw01.xxxx.cz.
xxxx.cz mail is handled by 10 e2sgw02.xxxx.cz.
```

..

```
root@medusa:~# telnet e2sgw01.xxxx.cz. 25
Trying 217.77.161.168...
Connected to e2sgw01.xxxx.cz.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 e2sgw01.xxxx.cz ESMTP Postfix
```

The problem was in /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf file (the chrooted one).
Have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable the **chroot** property so that its not changerooted the `/etc/postfix/master.cf` as documented [here](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#no_chroot)

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

to

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

Answer (score 2):

I able to resolve it by telling to Postfix to use Google DNS , right after Installing postfix:

```
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: nameserver in postfix can be multiple, or just singular?

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are behind a proxy : gmail.com address is resolved, but the ping command does not succeed.
You can try to connect directly gmail's SMTP with :

```
nc -w 1 gmail.com 25 ; echo $?
```

if it echoes "1", you can't connect, probably cause of security filtering.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shadur pointed out, this issue could be due to your ISP (or the network where your server is installed). If there is a security restrictions on the SMTP port (port number 25), MX servers cannot by reached via this port.

You could try to use the SMTP over SSL port (ssmtp, port number 465) instead. To do this, edit the `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file, comment the smtp line and add a ssmtp line instead :

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
ssmtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

To check that this post is recognized with this name on your machine, you can do :

```
$>cat /etc/services | grep smtp
smtp        25/tcp      mail
ssmtp       465/tcp     smtps       # SMTP over SSL
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case postfix starts up before the system has finished network initialization. So the /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf is empty.

When I restart postfix, it is no longer empty.

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

After that the mail queue slowly drains.

Answer (score -1):

```
mkdir /var/spool/postfix/etc
cp /etc/resolv.conf /var/spool/postfix/etc/
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit terse and could be improved by explaining the issue, i.e., the underlying cause of the problem and why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question.